# Unable to locate a class or view for component [listing-card]

Tags: laravel-9

```
@foreach($listings as $listing)
<x-listing-card :listing="$listings" />
@endforeach
```

the 'listing-card is in the component folder.

It should have shown a result without error but I got this

[image]

I am a beginner web developer, please help me out

Comment: show the folder structure of the components folder in resources/views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the array, than the model, instead you should do the following:

```
@foreach($listings as $listing)
   <x-listing-card :listing="$listing" />
@endforeach
```

*Read more on Component Blading here:* https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#component-methods